# ca65: Include Guard generates "Error: Identifier expected"

Tags: assembly, 6502, c64, ca65

Trying to learn how to use the ca65 assembler, I've been battling with making **include guards** work. Googling and reading the *ca65 Users Guide* didn't help. Here's a minimal example that produces the error.

```
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  60 Oct 22 19:40 65.inc
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  55 Oct 22 20:01 test.s
$
$ cat 65.inc
.ifndef _65_INC_
.define _65_INC_

.define NUMBER 1

.endif
$
$ cat test.s
.include "65.inc"
.include "65.inc"

    lda #NUMBER
    rts
$
$ ca65 test.s
65.inc(1): Error: Identifier expected
65.inc(2): Error: Identifier expected
65.inc(4): Error: Identifier expected
65.inc(4): Note: Macro was defined here
$
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  60 Oct 22 19:40 65.inc
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  55 Oct 22 20:01 test.s
$
```

If I only include `65.inc` *once* in `test.s` it assembles without problem, as seen here:

```
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  60 Oct 22 19:40 65.inc
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  37 Oct 22 20:07 test.s
$
$ cat 65.inc
.ifndef _65_INC_
.define _65_INC_

.define NUMBER 1

.endif
$
$ cat test.s
.include "65.inc"

    lda #NUMBER
    rts
$
$ ca65 test.s
$
$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   60 Oct 22 19:40 65.inc
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  295 Oct 22 20:07 test.o
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   37 Oct 22 20:07 test.s
$
$ ca65 --version
ca65 V2.17 - Git 153bb29
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly `.ifndef` and friends apply to **symbols** which macros are not (`.define` defines a macro). Thus a possible workaround is to use a symbol, e.g.

```
.ifndef _65_INC_
_65_INC_ = 1

.define NUMBER 1

.endif
```

Comment: Thanks Jester, that makes sense. My code was inspired by the source in the first download link at: (https://csdb.dk/release/?id=32392) where he does use a .define  I wonder why it works for him and not for me?

Comment: It doesn't work there either, it's just that the guards are never actually used since no file is included twice. As in your case, if you only include once then there is no error (but the whole exercise is unnecessary then of course).

Comment: Haha ok, even the elite are only human :)  Thanks for explaining.